# Why do human beings have enmity towards snakes? (Catholic perspective)

Tags: catholicism, genesis

Following is an excerpt from an article appearing in LiveScience:

> Fear of snakes is one of the most common phobias, yet many people have never seen a snake in person. New research suggests humans have evolved an innate tendency to sense snakes — and spiders, too — and to learn to fear them.
>   Psychologists found that both adults and children could detect images of snakes among a variety of non-threatening objects more quickly than they could pinpoint frogs, flowers or caterpillars. The researchers think this ability helped humans survive in the wild.

My question is: Is the fear of and enmity towards snakes inherent in human beings  an after-effect of the curse which fell on the serpent in Eden? Do the teachings of Catholic Church discuss this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the LiveScience quote?

Comment: https://www.livescience.com/2348-fear-snakes.html